Firebase App Check (DeviceCheck / AppAttest ion iOS) not working properly
I have set up a test app to try out Firebase App Check (DeviceCheck / App Attest) for my iOS / SWIFT Project using Firebase. Everything has been set up according to the documentation on the Firebase website, and still … I get no access to a document collection in Firestore secured with authentication requirements. Authentication against a service account (which I use in my Python scripts) works fine, though.
Here is the actual CODE for the AppDelegate of my App:
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAppCheck

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
            // Use App Attest for iOS 14+ devices, and DeviceCheck for older iOS devices
            let providerFactory = SGAppCheckProviderFactory()
            AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
            
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            
            print("XXXXX Firestore db ready: \(db)")
            
            AppCheck.appCheck().token(forcingRefresh: false) { token, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("XXXXX Error getting App Check token: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else if let token = token {
                    print("XXXXX App Check token: \n\n\(token.token)")
                }
            }
            
            // Trigger a Firestore request to ensure App Check is working
            db.collection("news").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("XXXXX Error fetching Firestore data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("XXXXX Successfully fetched Firestore data")
                }
            }

        return true
    }

}

class SGAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
    func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            print("XXXXX Using AppAttestProviderFactory for iOS 14+")
            return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
        } else {
            print("XXXXX Using DeviceCheckProviderFactory for iOS 11-13")
            return DeviceCheckProvider(app: app)
        }
    }
}




In my Xcode Project, I have added the Capability „App Attest"

In the Firebase console I have set up Device Check for all my Apps including this test app in the current project.

I have generated a key with the purpose DeviceCheck on my Apple Developer Account and uploaded it to Firebase, supplied the KeyID and my Team ID. Both DeviceCheck and App Attest are fully configured in the Firebase console. Device check got the Key file and the Key ID, I extracted. My Group ID is directly copy/pasted from me Developer Account.

App Check is enforced in the Firebase Console. I can see the requests in the Monitoring.


My database contains a collection called „news“.
SECURITY RULES for my Firestore dbs in this Firestor project are:
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null || request.appCheck.token != null;
    }
  }
}


When I let the App run with extended debugging info provided by the -FIRDebugEnabled flag. I get a long debugging output, but in the end it always gets to:
11.4.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (8093ef0401) response: <ListenResponse 0x16b4ae640>: {
  target_change {
    target_change_type: REMOVE
    target_ids: 2
    cause {
      code: 7
      message: "Missing or insufficient permissions."
    }
  }
}


This happens, no matter if App Checking is enforced or not and no matter, if I am using Device Check or App Attestation (I hard-coded that into the Factory Class for testing purposes). Results are the same.
Crazy enough, when I check the monitoring for App Check in Firebase, each request coming from my app running on a physical device is counted as „Verified Request" (the number of verified requests grows and grows over the course of the testing) but access keeps being denied "Code 7: Missing or insufficient permissions".
It works fine from Python using a service account. The method I use in Python is NOT acceptable to use for a distributed app, though, because it would require to distribute the confidential credentials in the app.
It seems as if I get the Token verified and then some issues happens.
In the XCode logs, I get the actual App Check token (which is generated and transmitted). When I take the token and check it in https://jwt.io it is obviously properly formatted, https://jwt.io says. 
 {
  "sub": "1:931036417710:ios:d8d931aab724edd90f273f",
  "aud": [
    "projects/XXXXXXXX“,
    "projects/sg-XXXXX“
  ],
  "provider": "device_check_device_identification",
  "iss": "https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/931036417710",
  "exp": 1729630106,
  "iat": 1729543706,
  "jti": "XXXX"
}


But at the same time, https://jwt.io says, too: 

Invalid Signature

  The latter might be the root cause for denying me access, of course. On the other hand, I don’t know where the token comes from exactly and what I could do to make sure it gets a „Valid Signature".
Doing Authentication with App Attest/Device Check seems like a really good idea and way more secure than storing credentials for service accounts somewhere in the source code. Unfortunately, setting this app seems to be way more complex (and sensitive for small mistakes/errors).
